# the angle formed by incenter, vertex and circumcenter

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the triangle $\triangle ABC$, $I$ is the incenter, $O$ is the circumcenter. Prove that $\angle ICO=\frac{|\angle A-\angle B|}{2}$.

[image]

I found this conclusion in steps of some proof. But I spent a day on it without answer. I used GeoGebra to test it. It was correct. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

I tried to connect $AI,BI$. Assuming $\angle B >\angle A$. I can draw $\angle IBE=\frac{\angle B-\angle A}{2}$. But I do not see how to relate it to the question angle.

[image]

@peterwhy solved this question in the comment part and reminded that I need to check the case when the circumcenter is outside of the triangle. So, I used GeoGebra to check that case. During this process, I fixed $B$ and $C$ and let $A$ moving around the circle. I found that the trace of the incenter $F$ is a union of two arcs. By GeoGebra, they are truly two arcs from two circles. I want to ask where are the centers of them and what are radii of these two circles.

[image]

Now I know the centers of these two arcs and the radii of them. I post the GeoGebra graph first here:

[image]

Because I move the point $A$ along the circumcircle. So its angle is fixed. The angle $\angle CDB=90^\circ+\frac{A}{2}$ after computation. Hence it is also fixed. So its trace will be an arc. This arc has the central angle $180^\circ -A$ and the radius will be the perpendicular bisector $BC$. Therefore the center is, the midpoint of the arc $BC$, $E$ on the circumcircle. The radius is $BE$. With the similar reason, the other arc has the center $F$, the midpoint of the greater arc $CAB$. The radius is $BF$.

DONE.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show some your steps.

Comment: Specifically, edit the question to add some thoughts you’ve put into the problem.

Comment: But also check if this holds if the circumcentre $O$ is outside the triangle.

Comment: $CI$ is the angle bisector of $\angle C$. $O$ being the circumcentre, $$\begin{align*}
\angle OCA &= \angle OAC
= \angle A-\angle OAB\\
\angle OCB &= \angle OBC
= \angle B-\angle OBA\\
\angle OAB &= \angle OBA\\
\angle OCA - \angle OCB &= \angle A - \angle B\\
\angle OCA-\frac{\angle C}2 + \frac{\angle C}2-\angle OCB &= \angle A-\angle B\\
2\angle ICO &= |\angle A -\angle B|
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @peterwhy, thanks a lot. I just see I put time in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\angle AOC=2\angle B$ $(\angle \text{at centre}=2\angle \text{at circumference})$

$\angle OCA=\angle OAC=90^0-\angle B$ $(\angle's \space  \text{are}= \text{opposite}=\text{sides})$

$\angle ICA=\angle ICB=\frac{\angle C}{2}$ (I is the incentre)

$\frac{\angle A}{2}+\frac{\angle B}{2}+\frac{\angle C}{2}=90^0$ (sum of $\angle$'s in $\triangle$)

$\angle OCI = \frac{\angle C}{2}-(90^0-\angle B)=90^0-(\frac{\angle A}{2}+\frac{\angle B}{2})-(90^0-\angle B)=\frac{\angle B}{2}-\frac{\angle A}{2}$

In general,

$\angle OCI =|\frac{\angle A}{2}-\frac{\angle B}{2}|$

Comment: from the first two lines, will $\angle B=30^\circ$?

Comment: This is a very nice proof. In line 4, should it be $\angle ICA=\angle ICB=\frac{\angle C}{2}$? I also do not see the usage of line 3 here.

Comment: @shanmumu - I have edited